# How to control the Android SurfaceView (canvas) redraw

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, redraw

I'm have a couple of images in a grid. 
Looks something like this: 
[http://cdn.thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/06/jolla4.jpg][1]

Instead of using android Gridview i have used a canvas, because the icons need to be animated. I read that i needed to use the canvas for games.

I am using a SurfaceView (in combination with a thread) to draw the images on the screen.

```
 class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //here i create the bitmaps and draw the icons on the screen.

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
```

This all works fine. Mysurface is called from within my main activity with the code:

```
setContentView(new MySurface());
```

The problem is the canvas of the surfaceview is redrawn at random. I want to make it so i can decide when the canvas is redrawn and how many times. How call the onDraw function from within the main activity? I don't know how to do that.

I know in the thread is is done with

> mySurface.onDraw(c);

Answer (score 2):

onDraw is called with each screen refresh. Screen refresh rate depends on your device. If refresh rate is 70, then your onDraw is called 70 times a second. onDraw is running on a seperate thread so I don't recommend messing with it by trying to call it from your UI thread. Calculate delta time which is the time passed since the last time onDraw was called. And let's say you want to animate your bitmap 50 pixels per second, then say 
    x += deltaTime * 50;

this will make your bitmap move only 50 pixels in x axis per second.

If you just say
   x += 1;

your bitmap will move screen refresh rate times per second. Since all devices have varying refresh rate, you need to use delta time in order to have screen updated in the same speed in all devices. Otherwise your animation speed would vary from device to device.

Comment: I see there is also  invalidate (). This is a method to redraw the view. "This must be called from a UI thread."

Comment: invalidate is called in onDraw to tell that onDraw should be called again. It is called by the thread that SurfaceView created.